# iText - Write Total Page Number in a new PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

using iText, I have to create a PDF with a big PdfPTable and, on the footer, the total pages number (something like 'page X of Y'). I took a look at [this](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#225-moviecountries1.java) exemple but I really don't understant how it works. At the moment my code is something like this:

```
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);

        //something to fill the table

        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.open();

        PdfTemplate totalPage = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);
        ColumnText columnTable = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        columnTable.addElement(table);

        while(true) {
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("Pag. " + String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber()),FONT_N), (document.right() - document.left())/ 2 + document.leftMargin(), document.bottom(), 0);

            //I think something to insert totalPage in the document...

            columnTable.setSimpleColumn(document.left(), document.top(), document.right(), Math.round(document.bottom()*1.5));

            if(!ColumnText.hasMoreText(columnTable.go()))
                break;

            document.newPage();
        }

        //I think something to set totalPage...

        document.close();
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Since you are new at iText, why are you using iText 5 or earlier? If you start with iText 7, you'll discover that adding page numbers is much easier. Read the [Jump-start](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial) and [Building blocks](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks) tutorials. Right now, you are looking at an *example* without reading a *tutorial* (such as the old "iText in Action" book). Stack Overflow is not a replacement for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Replace while loop with below code:

```
ColumnText columnTable = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        columnTable.addElement(table);
        PdfTemplate totalPage = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);
        try {
            table.setWidths(new int[]{24, 24, 2 });
            table.setTotalWidth(527);
            table.setLockedWidth(true);
            table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
            table.addCell("");
            table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            table.addCell(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()));
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(totalPage));
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
            table.addCell(cell);
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(totalPage, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 
                    new Phrase( String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber())), 
                    0, 0, 0);
        }
        catch(DocumentException de) {
throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
```

}

Comment: You should improve your answer with an explanation, what your code does and why this solves the problem of the OP. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)